# How can I read a File from another maven module?

Tags: java, maven, file, path, inputstream

My Project looks like:

```
project:
├── pom.xml
│
├── project-base
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── com
│                   └── company
│                       └── project
│                           └── util
│                               └── io
│                                   └── YamlReader
│ 
├── project-algo
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── com
│                   └── company
│                       └── project
│                           └── AlgorithmTest
│
└── project-config
    ├── pom.xml
    └── configs
        └── application_config.yaml
```

on the AlgorithmTest I have to read some values from application_config.yaml which is located in another maven module.

To read yaml file I created a utility interface called YamlReader that uses
jackson-dataformat-yaml.

At the moment I didn't find a way to read file from another module, so I'm copying the application_config.yaml into the src/test/resources folder of the project-algo module, but it's not ok, every time I have to change somthing on the application_config.yaml, I need to update both file.

I'm using the following method:

```
public static <C extends ConfigParent> C readConfiuration(Class<C> configClass, String yamlFileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("./src/test/resources/" + yamlFileName));

    YAMLMapper mapper = new YAMLMapper();
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);

    return mapper.readValue(inputStream, configClass);
}
```

This works fine for each Yaml file located into the src/test/resources folder of the project-algo module.

To read from project-config module I tried the following code:

```
public static <C extends ConfigParent> C readConfiuration(Class<C> configClass, String yamlFileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("./project-config/configs/" + yamlFileName));
    
    YAMLMapper mapper = new YAMLMapper();
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
    
    return mapper.readValue(inputStream, configClass);
}
```

and also

```
public static <C extends ConfigParent> C readConfiuration(Class<C> configClass, String yamlFileName) throws IOException {
    
    Module specificModule = ModuleLayer.boot()
        .findModule("project-config")
        .orElseThrow(IOException::new);
    InputStream inputStream = specificModule.getResourceAsStream(yamlFileName);
    
    YAMLMapper mapper = new YAMLMapper();
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
    
    return mapper.readValue(inputStream, configClass);

}
```

but it doesn't work.

Maybe can be helpful, poms are configured in the following way:

project pom.xml contains all the modules:

```
<modules>
    <module>project-config</module>
    <module>project-base</module>
    <module>project-algo</module>
</modules>
```

project-algo pom.xml contains the dependency of project-base :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>project-base</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

It is possible to read file without adding project-config as dependency of project-algo?

Comment: Why is the test which is reading a configuration in a different module than the config itself? And what should being tested? Apart from that why do you have a separate directory instead of `src/test/resources` or `src/main/resources`?

Comment: If the config is only for testing why not putting the configuration into `src/test/recources` in the appropriate module?

Comment: no, I just simplify, I didn't write all the classes. project-config has only the application.java and a lot of yaml file into the configs folder. project-algo is where all the algorithms elaborate data, and to test algorithms I need to use some property of the application_config.yaml (for example columns and order for csv file) ... so it's not a test of reading the yaml file, it's a test of the Algorithm, this is why it's on project-algo module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("./project-config/configs/" + yamlFileName));
```

I fix the problem using

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("../project-config/configs/" + yamlFileName));
```

There is no need to have the Project-Config as a dependency.

**./** -> start to search from the maven module location

**../** -> start to search from parent maven module

Answer (score 0):

Seems project-config is a sibling module. Add its dependency in your project-algo pom and run "mvn clean package"

Comment: It is possible to read file without adding project-config as dependency of project-algo?